# Securing a public exposed LAN port

Tags: switch, vlan, powerline-networking, managed

At my home, I have a relatively common network setup with a modem (in bridge mode), two ASUS mesh routers (ethernet backhaul) and a few unmanaged switches.

Now I need to have internet connectivity in the basement garage, which is somewhat a public place. For this, I connected one Devolo Powerline Adapter to my router, and one in the Garage. Unfortunately, there is also a LAN port at the adapter. I want to prevent someone connecting to my home network.

Now I'm asking my self what would be the best/cheapest way to isolate this port. Internet through WLAN should be possible but no home network access through the RJ45 port.

Could it be solved with a managed switch? What would be the feature I need for this? VLAN?

Comment: What's wrong with a firewall?

Comment: Put it on a separate network with firewalling. In Office/Company settings you would use 802.1x for authentication, but that is for the port from the switch and probably won't help.

There is also the option to use dummy plugs with locks, easy to circumvent, but it depends on which layer of security you actually need.

Comment: @NiKiZe Thanks, dummy plug with locks seems to be good enough, didn't know they exists. Regarding separate network and firewall, what feature am I looking for in network products? Achievable with Ubiquiti Switch EdgeSwitch ES-10X for example?

Comment: Devolo won't let me look at the instruction manuals without registration, but it is possible that there is an option to disable the Ethernet port, which is cheaper than a physical lock.